# how to integrate redmine with git, to close issues?

Tags: git, integration, redmine

I had install Bitnami Redmine on my Windows 7
I want to close the issue when I make a commit. it should update the issue status in redmine.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with reading Redmine's wiki [page](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineSettings) on SCM integration. It seems pretty thorough.

Comment: I have already read that! In the documentation they say that you have to specify the status if you want to enable auto closure of issues.                        http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineSettings#Issue-tracking

Comment: Yes, and have you made it working?